# Add drop and drop and copy paste two ways on Linux

Tags: linux, gtk, linux-mint

TLDR: How can I add both drop and drop and copy paste between my desktop application and the default Linux file manager? I am using a GTK based desktop environment,

I am writing a FOSS S3 desktop client for Linux. S3, short for Simple Storage Service, has become a cloud file API standard designed by Amazon and now supported by Google, Microsoft, Digital Ocean, IBM, Wasabi and the open source personal S3 server MinIO among others.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a nice free and open graphical desktop client for S3 compatible services and have decided to write my own. It's coming along nicely, but I want to add the ability to drag and drop cloud files in S3 buckets between my application and the desktop, as well as copy and paste both ways.

[image: screenshot]

I don't know where to begin with this and need some advice or a nudge in the correct direction.

I want to have a design where users can simply drag objects from my application onto the default Linux file manager and my application will know where the objects were dropped and begin downloading those files.

I also want to be able to copy objects onto the clipboard in my application and be notified where they were pasted by the default Linux file manager and begin downloading files to that location after being notified of a paste action.

I am using a Mint flavor of Linux with GTK and have no idea how to implement these features. I am hopeful someone here might be able to offer me some relevant and useful advice.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Is your application developed in Gtk or QT? Gtk's DnD engine is reasonably simple and well documented, but in the case of QT, and the interaction between QT and Gtk, things can be a little more complicated.